# How to update JavaScript files with version number parameter from Razor page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I would like to update JavaScript files for every release. So, I need to add the version number to the JavaScript files which i am using and I would like to give the version number from the web.config file.

I had added a key in the web.config as:

```
  <add key="VersionNumber" value="1"/>
```

I have an js file as:

```
  <script src="~/Scripts/Utilities/DashBoard.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I know we can give "version number" to the js file like:

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/Utilities/DashBoard.js?version="**data**""     type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In asp.net mvc3 razor we can get the value from web.config in javascript as:

```
var VersionData =   "@System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VersionNumber"].ToString()";
```

But i had an confusion how to place this "VersionData" in the "data" of the above script line.

And I had given this VersionData in the page load function. Is it correct?

When I change the version number for every release will it update .js file. Can any one please help me to find the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the `WebConfigurationManager` class from `System.Web.Configuration` namespace instead.

**Example**

```
string versionNumber = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["VersionNumber"].ToString()
```

In order to use the version parameter in your .js library, I'd recommend passing your arguments through an object.

**In DashBoard.js**

```
var MYSCRIPT = MYSCRIPT || (function(){ 
    var _args = {};

    return { 
        init : function(Args) { 
            _args = Args; 
        }, 
    returnValue : function() { 
             alert(_args[0]); 
         } 
    }; 
}());
```

**Your Razor Page**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/Utilities/DashBoard.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   MYSCRIPT.init(["versionNumber", @versionNumber]); 
</script>
```

**Accessing the value (either in your page or JS)**

```
 MYSCRIPT.returnValue();
```

I would recommend creating your own Html helper to obtain the active script name from your web.config.

Comment: okay Thank you for your response. But how to place this versionNumber in .js script file.. i had this .js script file in index.cshtml

Comment: I added an example of how to pass this parameter to your .js file using a namespace. I hope this helps you.